# How to update an FFmpeg SVN installation to the latest version

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg svn-r26402 – is this stable or not?

I searched and found that the SVN repository is old and the Git repository is new.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The FFmpeg developers don't maintain their SVN repository anymore. It's really not that hard to get the latest Git source though. From the [FFmpeg download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html):

> You can retrieve the source code through the standard Git client by
>   using the command:
>
> ```
> git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
> ```

If you don't want to build the binaries yourself, you can also pick a static build  for Linux, Windows, or OS X. Simply scroll down the download page.